# Does my file system implemented using the Composite pattern require a singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm exploring [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to write a file system, one of my requirements is to create a unique root element in this case a directory, similar to Linux System ('/'), I have seen many examples of creating this in the client like this:

```
class CompositeDemo
{
    public static StringBuffer g_indent = new StringBuffer();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Directory one = new Directory("dir111");
        Directory two = new Directory("dir222");
        Directory thr = new Directory("dir333");
        File a = new File("a");
        File b = new File("b");
        File c = new File("c");
        File d = new File("d");
        File e = new File("e");
        one.add(a);
        one.add(two);
        one.add(b);
        two.add(c);
        two.add(d);
        two.add(thr);
        thr.add(e);
        one.ls();
    }
}
```

Source: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite/java/1

Since my requirement is to create a unique root node is it best practice to create a new Class that has only one root element? Can I use a Singleton design pattern?

Comment: That composite pattern is really bad example. Files and directories don't have much in common. At least for the client.

Comment: Title says "Composite pattern", the question is about Singleton. Why?

Comment: @Euphoric files and directories is a common example of the Composite pattern where file is the leaf participant and folder is a the composite (can contain files or other folders)

Comment: @Basilevs Im referring that if I can mix both Composite patters and SIngleton, I refer to Singleton as I only want to specify a unique root element. I can define it as the initial directory container, but want to see if this is desirable. Thanks

Comment: @spicyramen To have a composite pattern, you need an interface that represents both leaf and the composite. I can't see any such interface for file and directory.

Comment: I understand, for simplicity source link contains complete code . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton is used when you want only a single instance of a class. This is often misapplied: it should only be used when multiple instances might cause a problem, not when it is convenient to have a single instance. Very rarely do I see a singleton that actually needs to be a singleton (but they do exist).

In this case, you will *not* have a single instance of the composite: you will have a single instance named "root." Every directory is a composite, with files as leaves.

I would just create your file system, and have a method that returns the root node upon request. In essence, the *file system* is behaving like a singleton, not the *composite object* itself.

In code, it would look like this:

```
private Directory root;

public Directory getRoot() {
  if (root == null) {
    root = createFileSystem();
  }
  return root;
}

private Directory createFileSystem() {
  Directory r = new Directory("");
  // Add more directories and files here.
  return r;
}
```

Note: I recommend doing it this way and not manipulating `root` directly in the creation logic to enforce [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and avoid threading bugs. It might be worth adding a Java `Lock` object if multiple threads may access `getRoot()` at once before the root is initialized. Separating the logic like this also makes it possible to reinitialize the file system while other threads are still using the old version, without causing threads to block.

Comment: `it should only be used when multiple instances might cause a problem`, Note sure it's the best argument, we could say the opposite : "use multiple classes when singleton might cause a problem". Singletons are a problem when you can't "mock" them for testing purposes, and when they aren't thread-safe.

Comment: @Walfrat Singletons have the drawback of creating a global state, something to be minimized or avoided. It's a pattern because it solves a problem, not because it should be sprinkled everywhere it does not cause too much harm. Your argument reads like "lets stab ourselves with knives as long as it does not hurt *too* much". That's wrong. Stabbing yourself with a knife might be a good thing in certain conditions, but it's not something to apply everywhere just because you can. Same goes for Singletons.

Comment: @nvoigt well I do use singletons a lot, because I do have quite a lot of objects that are stateless. But I use IOC for managing them, I don't hardwire singleton with static methods.

Comment: @Walfrat A stateless singleton does not make any sense. The only purpose of a singleton is to make sure the state is kept at a central point once. Are you sure we are talking about the same thing?

Comment: @nvoigt Well a unique instance of an object, that may have dependency but those won't change once set at runtime. So it does have a state when it has dependency, but they don't change.

Comment: @Walfrat An object has a state when it holds data. Any kind. For example  variables. If a Singleton has no such state, it's pointless.

Comment: @nvoigt a dependency is hold in a class as an attributes, so it does go with what I said :)